# SSSD with LDAP makes apparmor very noisy in syslog

Tags: apparmor, sssd

When loging in with SSSD configured against LDAP, syslog becomes very noisy with apparmor messages. This is somewhat annoying when scanning the logs for valuable information.

Maybe someone already solved this and can make life easier sharing their solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You can define filters in syslog to filter out certain messages - I have done that for several apps that I thought was spamming the syslog. [Link](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html)

Comment: I also would like a fix to this, it makes debugging important things in dmesg much harder.

Answer (score 2):

I am also getting several messages in `dmesg` related to `sssd`, after recently configuring domain membership.

Even though the messages were related to installing/configuring `sssd`, I am pretty sure the messages were actually from `apparmor`, since I tried adjusting `debug_level` in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`, which only had an effect on `/var/log/sssd/sssd.conf` and `systemctl status sssd.service`

Example:

```
# journalctl --reverse | grep sssd

. . . 
Jan 27 13:50:04 chubbychipmunk.webtool.space audit[39674]: 
AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" 
profile="/usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be//null-/usr/bin/nsupdate"
name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libirs.so.1601.0.0" 
pid=39674 
comm="nsupdate" 
requested_mask="r" 
denied_mask="r" 
fsuid=0 ouid=0
. . .
```

I am no `apparmor` expert, but through this process I learned of some utilities that appear to have helped `dmesg` be less noisy.

First, I installed `apparmor-utils`, which has the `aa-logprof` utility:

> From aa-logprof(8):
>
> Running aa-logprof will scan the log file and if there are new AppArmor events
> that are not covered by the existing profile set, the user will be prompted with
> suggested modifications to augment the profile.

```
% sudo apt install -y apparmor-utils
```

Then, I ran `aa-logprof` as root and got something like this:

```
% sudo aa-logprof

Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.
Reading log entries from /var/log/audit/audit.log.

WARNING: Ignoring exec event in /usr/sbin/sssd//null-/usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be, nested profiles are not supported yet.

Profile:  /usr/sbin/sssd
Execute:  /usr/libexec/sssd/ldap_child
Severity: unknown

(I)nherit / (C)hild / (P)rofile / (N)amed / (U)nconfined / (X) ix On / (D)eny / Abo(r)t / (F)inish
```

I used `(I)nherit` here to use the same profile as `sssd`.  Then I got something like this:

```
Complain-mode changes:
Enforce-mode changes:

= Changed Local Profiles =

The following local profiles were changed. Would you like to save them?

 [1 - /usr/sbin/sssd]
(S)ave Changes / Save Selec(t)ed Profile / [(V)iew Changes] / View Changes b/w (C)lean profiles / Abo(r)t
```

I hit `s` to save the profile, and exit, which should give you something like this:

```
Writing updated profile for /usr/sbin/sssd.
```

The first time I updated the profile, there were several processes that were not in the `sssd` profile yet. I basically just hit `(A)llow` for all of them since, in my case, all the processes `apparmor` was complaining about were related to `sssd`.

After a while to check and see if it worked, I ran:

```
% sudo dmesg -T | tail -n 100
```

And saw that the last `apparmor` message I had related to `sssd` was over two hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable it by running:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sssd
```

Source: https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2020/12/03/disable-apparmor-for-sssd/